# Как реализовать одновременное нажатие двух Button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как можно реализовать одновременное нажатие двух `Button`?

Задача такая:

- если кнопка `Button1` нажата, то при нажатии `Button3` выводиться
  сообщение "*Button1+Button3*";
- если кнопка `Button2` нажата, то при    нажатии `Button4` выводиться
  сообщение "*Button2+Button4*".

Допустим есть такой код:

```
private void Category1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if((Control)sender == Button1)
    {
         if((Control)sender == Button3)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Button1+Button3");
         }
         else if((Control)sender == Button4)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Button1+Button4");
         }

    }

    if((Control)sender == Button2)
    {
         if((Control)sender == Button4)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Button2+Button4");
         }
    }
}
```

Проблема кода в том, что условная конструкция `if((Control)sender == Button3)` не срабатывает (по причине того, что после нажатия на `Button3` `Button1` не нажата). Так вот, нужно сделать так, чтобы нажатие `Button1` сохранялось, пока, к примеру, не нажата `Button2`. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 5):

Один из вариантов использовать `Checkbox` элементы, стилизованные под `button`.

Вот пример только для `button1` и `button3`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //Добавил для простоты стилизацию чекбоксов в это место
    checkBox1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    checkBox3.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button1+Button3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Самый простой и эффективный метод, imho.

Answer (score -2):

К сожалению ответа так и нет.Пришлось делать с помощью Bool,то есть если нажать на Button1,bool примет значение true.А дальше уже можно выстроить следующий блок.

Comment: Ну, логично, так и надо. Будет совсем хорошо, если код приведёте.